# Dynamic key=>value segments in Zend Router

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3, zend-route

Need to achieve dynamic router param segmenting in Zend Router. The idea is: 
have the url: `/route/:route/resource/:resource/:identifier`, with the following configuration:

```
    'orchestration.rest.dynamic-router' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/route/:route/resource/:resource[/:identifier]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Controller',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

Need to make it support n-number different key=>value router params in the following format:

`/route/:route/resource/:resource/:identifier/key1/value1/key2/value2/key3/value3`

The second problem is that this should work only if you have the optional :identifier parameter provided.

This is what I've checked, but not sure how to achieve the goal: 
https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-router/routing/#zend92router92http92segment

Comment: If you want to make this work using only the router, I think you'll need to create a custom route type. Otherwise, you can do this work inside the controller. When you're inside your action, if `:identifier` variable is set, then you check the route for optional key/values.

Answer (score 0):

Leave static routes.
1) They are cached for better performance 
2) if you use rest logic, use POST method, not GET(params in url)

### the route

```
'orchestration.rest' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'routerest' => '/routerest/:action',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Controller',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

### use post to consume rest action on server, with Ajax, or other...

```
 (pseudo code)
 datas={key1 : param1 , key2 : param2, etc...}
   url=yourDomain/routerest/show   (show=the action)
   send Ajax Request(or something else in another langage with METHOD=POST)
```

### other action like "getdatas"

```
 ... use post to consume rest action on server, with Ajax, or other...
   datas={id1 : param1 , id2 : param2, etc...}
   url=yourDomain/routerest/getdatas   (getdatas=the action)
```

... in your Controller.php
   ...handle show action in route

```
  function showAction()  {
      $request = $this->getRequest();
      if ($request->isPost()) {
            $param1=$this->params()->fromPost('key1','defaultvalue');
            $param2=$this->params()->fromPost('key2','defaultvalue');
            ...
            ...
      } else {... ERROR..}
   }
```

...handle getdatas action in route

```
 function getdatasAction()  {
      $request = $this->getRequest();
      if ($request->isPost()) {
            $id1=$this->params()->fromPost('id1','defaultvalue');
            $id2=$this->params()->fromPost('id2','defaultvalue');
            ...
            ...
            if ($id1$=='all') { return $this->redirect()->toRoute ('otherroute', array ('action' => 'xxx', 'paramxxx' => 'xx'));
            ...
            ...
      } else {... ERROR..}
   }
```